# Can you create anonymous code blocks in Lua?

Tags: lua, anonymous

In programming languages such as C you can create an anonymous code block to limit the scope of variables to inside the block can the same be done with Lua?

If so what would be the Lua equivalent of the following C code?

```
void function()
{
    {
        int i = 0;
        i = i + 1;
    }

    {
        int i = 10;
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: In Lua, all blocks are anonymous, anyway. The sugary syntax of some [function definitions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11) are just stylistic ways of combining a function definition with an assignment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use `do...end`. From the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.2):

> A block can be explicitly delimited to produce a single statement:
>
> ```
> stat ::= do block end
> ```
>
> Explicit blocks are useful to control the scope of variable
>   declarations. Explicit blocks are also sometimes used to add a `return`
>   or `break` statement in the middle of another block

```
function fn()
    do
        local i = 0
        i = i + 1
    end
    do
        local i = 10
        i = i + 1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You can delimit a block with keyword `do` & `end`.

Reference: [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Running an anonymous function happens as follows:
`(function(a,b) print(a+b) end)(1,4)`

It outputs 5.